# Get audio device name in Ubuntu using Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, audio

I'm trying to list all my audio devices with the same names used by Ubuntu. For example, Ubuntu lists Speakers as a Built-in Audio and Headphones as Logitech USB Headset, but I can't get the same names when I list my devices with javax.sound.sampled. My code follows bellow:

```
Mixer.Info[] infoMixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

for (Mixer.Info infoMixer : infoMixers) {
    // Get mixer for each info
    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(infoMixer);
    String mixerName = infoMixer.getName();
    System.out.println("MIXER NAME: " + mixerName);
    System.out.println("MIXER : " + infoMixer.toString());
    System.out.println("MIXER DESC: " + infoMixer.getDescription());

    // Check if is input device
    Line.Info[] lines = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
    if (lines.length > 0) {
        for (Line.Info line : lines) {
            if (line.getLineClass().equals(TargetDataLine.class)) {
                System.out.println("LINE INFO: " + line.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    // Check if is output device
    lines = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
    if (lines.length > 0) {
        for (Line.Info line : lines) {
            if (line.getLineClass().equals(SourceDataLine.class)) {
                System.out.println("LINE INFO: " + line.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I list my devices with the same names used by Ubuntu?

Comment: It was a stackobverflow sugestion, so I used it.

Comment: you should includ just relevant information

Comment: removed Android tag.

Answer (score 1):

More than 4 years later:

`System.out.println(String.format("Name [%s]\n", line.getName()));`