# How do you get microphone / speaker names?

Tags: java, javasound

I'm interested in using the Java sound API for finding out the names of all available microphone / audio input devices, and audio output devices / speakers.

I tried the following to view what information can be provided from DataLine.Info:

```
final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(22000, 16, 2, true, true);
                final TargetDataLine line;
                final DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
                System.out.println(info.toString());
```

This gave the following output:

> interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 22000.0 Hz, 16
>   bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian

Which doesn't give a name of the device, though it does give some useful information.

**In short: how do I use the Java Sound API (or an external library) find audio input / output information?**

*For anyone interested, I need the names of the devices as I'm trying to automate the set up of some Virtual Audio Cables (VACs), following [the guide here](https://helping-squad.com/advanced-vac-virtual-audio-cable-guide/), which requires certain parameters, and I'd rather not have the user type them out!*

Comment: The `Mixer.Info` array returned by `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` has some limited information about mixers. There isn't much else that reports names of anything.

Comment: maybe helpful or useful: [Get audio device name in Ubuntu using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202918/get-audio-device-name-in-ubuntu-using-java)

Comment: See the `MediaTypes` source code on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556) for obtaining all the useful information that the Java Sound API will provide.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks Andrew. I'll water down that answer and post a simpler version of the code for anyone else who wants to reuse it.